# ical change color shading day and weekend

Tags: ical, color

Is it possible to change the shading of the selected day/today/weekend in iCal?

The light blue tone which is used to mark the current Day is almost impossible to recognise. Same Problem different color on the highlighted days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked on the Internet before, and no one has ever found an answer.

The 'fixes' that have been suggested are all just to improve your computer screen's contrast.
One way to do that is to go to the Universal Access pane of System Preferences. Play with the Enhance Contrast slider in the Seeing tab.

Sorry there isn't a better way to do this.

Comment: Sad that there doesn't exist a solution for this problem, I will for now mark your response as answer. (Hopefully some superhero will create an app which makes it possible to change the shading colors of ical)